# simplify radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, radicals, nested-radicals

In the book $A=B$ [(link)](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.pdf) page 11 example 1.5.1 it is written

> By setting $\sin a = x$ and $\sin b = y$, we see that the identity $\sin(a + b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$ is equivalent to
> $$
>  \arcsin x + \arcsin y = \arcsin(x \sqrt{1-y^2} + y \sqrt{1-x^2})
> $$
> When $x = 0$ this is tautologous, so it suffices to prove that the derivatives of both sides with respect to $x$ are the same. This is a routinely verifiable algebraic identity.

By differentiating w.r.t. $x$ I obtained:
\begin{gather}\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}}+ \frac {\frac{dy}{dx}} {\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}}
=\frac{\frac d {dx}\left (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1\!-\!x^2}\right)}
{\sqrt{1-\left (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1\!-\!x^2}\right)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}\!-\!\frac {xy}{\sqrt{1\!-\!x^2}}+\left(\sqrt{1\!-\!x^2}\!-\!\frac {xy}{\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}}\right)
\!\frac{dy}{dx}} {\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}
\end{gather}

where $y$ is somewhat arbitrary function of $x$. But I cannot reduce this (especially the radical in the denominator of the RHS) to show that the equality holds. Seems to me there is no way they can be equal so do I just assume it is a mistake in the text or is there someone who can show equality?

He seems to go about it by implying the squares of both sides are equal using Maple code but I can't show that either (and I don't have Maple so i can't test it that way).

---

*Petkovšek, Marko; Wilf, Herbert S.; Zeilberger, Doron*, $A=B$. With foreword by Donald E. Knuth, Wellesley, MA: A. K. Peters. xii, 212 p. (1996). [ZBL0848.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0848.05002).

Comment: What is "AeqB"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Comment: $y$ is not an arbitrary function of $x$ but an independent variable. So  $\frac {dy} {dx}=0$ and $\frac d {dx} \arcsin(y) =0$

Comment: the Maple program will return 0, so I think it would not be very helpful to you to run the Maple program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity is false. The left-hand side can take any value between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, whereas the right-hand side can only take on values in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

For instance, if $y=1$, you'd like to prove that
$$
\arcsin x+\frac{\pi}{2}=\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
Is this valid? Not for all $x\in[-1,1]$. The derivatives are *not* equal. Indeed, the derivative of the right-hand side is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)}}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\frac{x}{|x|}\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
which is the same as $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ only for $x\in(-1,0)$.

Check at Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kavz3yliyt

Comment: This can be resolved with using non-principal branches, can it not? On your Desmos graph, I also graphed $\sin(f(x))$ and $\sin(g(x))$ and the two graphs were equal! Although I suppose that while the main identity holds (of differing branches are accepted) it is possible that the derivatives are not consistent across branches - is that the case?

Comment: @FShrike As I showed, the derivatives are *not* equal. Their squares are, but…

Answer (score 0):

Note: Check also [egreg's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217764/11206) about the validity of this equation.

How to proof that
$$\arcsin(x)+\arcsin(y)=\arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})\tag{1}$$
holds?
From the book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) by *Marko Petkovsek*, *Herbert Wilf*, and *Doron Zeilberger* (Example 1.5.1 on page 11):

> When $x = 0$ this is tautologous, so it suffices to prove that the derivatives of both sides with respect to $x$ are the same.

Yes, because if $x=0$ the left side is $\arcsin(y)$ and the right side is $\arcsin(y)$.

So let's check if the derivates of both sides with respect to $x$ are the same.
Note that $y$ is not a function of $x$ as the OP assumes, but $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, so $\frac d{dx}y=0$, because $\frac d{dx}\text{const}=0.$
The OP already calculated the derivates and if we consider that $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ we get:

$$\frac{d}{dx } \arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}\!-\!\frac {xy}{\sqrt{1\!-\!x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}$$
$$=\frac {\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}-xy} {\sqrt{1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}}$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\frac {\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}-xy}{\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}}$$
$$=\pm \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

because
$$\Bigg({\frac {\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}-xy}{\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}}\Bigg)^2=1$$
can be easily shown.
So $$\frac {\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}-xy}{\sqrt{1-\left  (x\sqrt{1\!-\!y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}}$$
is either $+1$ or $-1$.

But [egreg's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217764/11206) shows us that this must not be the case that the sign is always $+1$.

But note that we have shown that the square of the derivate of the left hand side with respect to $x$ is equal to the square of the derivate of the right hand side with respect to $x$. The book authors leave this proof to Maple.

The book can bee downloaded [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/AeqB.pdf).

The book shows the following Maple program

```
f:=arcsin(x) + arcsin(y) :
g:= arcsin(x*(1-y**2)**( 1/2) + y*(1-x**2)**(1/2));
f1:=diff(f,x): g1:=diff(g,x):
normal(simplify(expand(g1**2))-f1**2);
```

So the first two lines define the functions that represent the LHS and the RHS of the equations. The third line calculates the derivates of these functions with respect to $x$ and the final line calculates f the difference of squares of these derivates. This should be $0$. The authors assist Maple to do these calculation by calculating the difference of the squares of the derivates instead of the difference of the derivates and by using the commands [`expand`](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=expand) , [`simplify`](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=simplify) and [`normal`](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=normal), which transform expressions to equivalent expression. I assume without these assistance Maple will return an expression containing a lot of square roots, similar to the expressions in our calculation and it is unclear if this expression is equals to $0$ or not. Note again that the authors request from Maple only to show that the squares of the derivattives are equal.

A free computer algebra system is [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/index.html). Here you can do the calculation with the following commands:

```
f:asin(x)+asin(y);
g:asin(x*sqrt(1-y^2)+y*sqrt(1-x^2));
f1:diff(f,x);
g1:diff(g,x);
ratsimp(g1^2-f1^2);
```

The last command does some simplifications and returns $0$.

You can try this out (at your own risk) [here](http://maxima.cesga.es)

Comment: i have been using maxima for years. It is somewhat useful esp being free but never have i seen such a program with so so many many bugs ! and not infrequently the only way to get out of it is ctrl-alt-delete losing all your work. Quite inconsistent and often giving WRONG answers , overwriting and changing itself illegibly etc etc. and even screwing up other programs one may have open. I wish i knew how to try the Linux program SageMath to run under Linux directly as an alternate operating system to windows. Has anyone tried that? And how do u judge it as compared to maxima or maple etc.

Comment: @user158293 I have the similar experience with regards to Maxima.

Comment: may sound like stupid question but in a little more detail what was your rationale as to the validity of setting dy/dx=0 ? or are u only saying ' if consider 
dy/dx=0  '  while it is not necessarily true?  Also by the way do u only use maxima on line or the complete installed software or both ?

Comment: @user158293 y is not a function of x, but x and y are independent variables, so $\frac d{dx}y=0$, because $\frac d{dx}\text{const}=0$

Comment: @user158293 I already mentioned this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217746/simplify-radicals/4217832?noredirect=1#comment8755812_4217746) but I added this to the answer now

Comment: I guess you could conceivably assume y is not a fct. of x as a special case but the way the problem is stated in the most general case would assume that y is a function of x because it is stated "...differentiating both sides wrt x..." for otherwise assuming as you did it would be the same as if the problem were stated "differentiating both sides wrt y..." and you would essentially reach the same conclusion{assuming in this latter case x is not a fct. of y}.

Comment: it is not conceivable that y is not a function of x, this is simply a fact. Nothing in the text it is assumed that y depends on x . In equation 1 x and y are independent variables. eq 1 is true if x=0 for any y. So y is viewed as a constant and x as a variable. If the first derivate with respect to x of the left and the right side are  equal in an interval that contains 0, then the left and the right side are equal in this interval for this y. This is a simple initial value problem. Of course the roles of x and y can be interchanged, then x is the constant and w derive with respect to y.